# Error embedding "\n" into a string literal

Tags: go

I need to decode a JSON string which has "\n" in it:

```
[
    {"Name":"Neo", "Message":"Hi\n:Hello everyone"},
    {"Name":"Sam","Messsage":"Hello\nEveery\nOne"}
]
```

I use the Golang code below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Messages  []string     `json:"Name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
s := "[{\"Name\":\"Neo\", \"Message\":\"Hi\n:Hello everyone\"},   {\"Name\":\"Sam\",\"Messsage\":\"Hello\nEveery\nOne\"}]"
var pro Person
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
if err == nil {
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
} else {
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
}
}
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR invalid character '\n' in string literal
```

Comment: Sorry. my bad. Updated the question

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the same site Mellow linked to?

Comment: stil doesn't give an error.

Comment: Pls check my updated question @tadman

Comment: Pls check my updated question @MellowMarmot

Comment: The problem you have is how you define the example string. In your example you have to double escape it like so: `"[{\"Message\": \"Hi\\n:Hello\"}]`.
But you should really use this syntax `\`[{"Message": "Hi\n:Hello"}]\`` for readability, as suggested in the play link in earlier comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few of issues here. The first is that newline is not allowed in a JSON string. Use the two bytes `\n` to specify a newline, not an actual newline. If you use an interpreted string literal, then the `\` must be quoted with a `\`. Example:

```
"Hello\\nWorld"
```

No quoting is required in a raw string literal:

```
`Hello\nWorld`
```

The next issue is that JSON value is an array of object values. To handle the array, unmarshal to a slice:

```
var pro []Person
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
```

To handle the objects, define Person as a struct:

```
type Person struct {
  Name    string
  Message string
}
```

[working example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UniPq3cvBR).

Answer (score 2):

Use backtick, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name    string `json:"Name"`
    Message string `json:"Message"`
}

func main() {
    s := `
[
    {"Name":"Neo", "Message":"Hi\n:Hello everyone"},
    {"Name":"Sam", "Message":"Hello\nEvery\nOne"}
]   
    `
    var pro []Person
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", pro)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(pro)

}
```

output:

```
[{"Neo" "Hi\n:Hello everyone"} {"Sam" "Hello\nEvery\nOne"}]

[{Neo Hi
:Hello everyone} {Sam Hello
Every
One}]
```

Comment: @hardy I hope this helps.